# pillow で透過画像をリサイズや、透明化すると背景が透過しなくなってしまう

Tags: python, pillow

thumbnailからputalpha処理までを消すと透過されるのですが、この処理を入れるとimageの透過部分が黒く見えてしまいます。
処理をした画像の透過を維持するにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

```
from PIL import Image

back = Image.open(背景).convert('RGBA')
image = Image.open(透過画像).convert('RGBA')

back.resize((1000,1000))
image.thumbnail((100,100))
image.putalpha(100)

image_clear = Image.new('RGBA',back.size,(255,255,255,0))
back.paste(image,(50,50),image)
back = Image.alpha_composite(back,image_clear)

back.show()
```

Comment: 差し支え無ければ使った背景と透過画像(の一部でも)を埋め込むかリンク場所を追記してみてください。

Comment: 背景は何も無い緑と透過画像はGoogleのロゴです。

Comment: Googleのロゴは透過画像なのですが、更にロゴ部分を半透明にして入れようとした所、上手く行きませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

おそらく、透過率を変更した後の`image`を`paste()`のmaskとして使用しているからでしょう。
透過率を変更する前のデータをmask用にコピーして、それを`paste()`のmaskとして指定すれば大丈夫ですね。
以下のように出来るでしょう。

```
from PIL import Image

back = Image.open('./bg.png').convert('RGBA')
image = Image.open('./glogo.png').convert('RGBA')


back.resize((1000,1000))
image.thumbnail((100,100))
mask = image.copy()  ## サイズ変更しただけの元画像をmaskとしてコピーする
image.putalpha(100)

image_clear = Image.new('RGBA',back.size,(255,255,255,0))
back.paste(image,(50,50),mask)  ## 透過率を変更していない元画像のアルファチャンネルをmaskに指定
back = Image.alpha_composite(back,image_clear)

back.show()
```

Comment: 追加で申し訳ありません。putalphaの値を0にした所完全な透明にならなかったのですが何故でしょうか？

Comment: 済みませんが仕組みや原理は知らないので分かりません。この仕様[Image.putalpha(alpha)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.putalpha)やこの記事[PIL/Pillow チートシート](https://qiita.com/pashango2/items/145d858eff3c505c100a)とかマルチポスト先の回答[pillow で　透過画像を　リサイズ、透明化すると背景が透過しなくなってしまう](https://teratail.com/questions/290567)とかを総合すると何か分かるかもしれません。元データの内容に依るのかもしれませんが。